# Rpi4 Qt5 Qml drmModeGetResources failed error

Tags: qt, qml, raspberry-pi4

I have been created a build with Buildroot. Also did it everthing on this comment -> https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=263418#p1614833
Did my research, and dozens of trials, and I get nothing.

My config is:
**Rpi4-64, QT5-Qml, Mesa v3d-vc4, opengl es 2.0**

When I try to run my qt qml application on this build, I'm getting this error:

**QStandardPaths: wrong permission on runtime directory /usr/bin/, 7755 instead of 7700
drmModeGetResources failed (Operation not supported)
no screens available, assuming 24 -bit color
Cannot create window: no screens available.**

Summary : I need to run my qt5 qml application on Rpi 4 with hw accelerated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.
I think the Rpi4 with eglfs using default card for **card0**, and this is not work. Need to force using **card1** for eglfs.

Create a file "eglfs.json" with the following content:

```
{ "device": "/dev/dri/card1" }
```

export QT_QPA_EGLFS_KMS_CONFIG=/wherever/is/the/file/eglfs.json
and run your qt app!

Also my qt5 qml program is not showing fonts or text on rpi4 buildroot system. Coping /usr/share/fonts/your_program_fonts worked for me.